# Equation of convolution of measures

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, convolution

Let $\mu_1,\mu_2$ be two locally finite complex regular Borel measures on $[0,+\infty)$ and $\delta_x$ be the Dirac measure at point $x\in[0,+\infty)$. Suppose that for all $x\in(0,+\infty)$ 
$$\delta_x*\mu_1=\delta_x*\mu_2.$$
Could we say that $\mu_1=\mu_2$?

Where $*$ is convolution of measures which is defined for measures $\mu,\nu$
$$\int_0^\infty\psi(x)d(\mu*\nu)(x)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\psi(x+y)d\mu(x)d\nu(y), \quad \psi\in C_0([0,+\infty)).$$
In other world could we conclude that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\delta_{\frac{1}{n}}*\mu=\delta_0*\mu$$
for all locally finite complex regular Borel measure $\mu$?

Comment: Can't you just convolve on the left by $\delta_{-x}$?

Comment: $-x\not\in [0,+\infty)$ for $x\in [0,+\infty)$

Comment: Doesn't matter. Extend all the measures to $\mathbb{R}$ and proceed....